# SQL table holding incremental counter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to update a table with a counter - its quite a simple setup.

The table will have no more than 10 rows. At present there is a PrimaryIndex on a 3-char string column (SiteCode) with a second column (NumVotes) holding a long number.

The idea is to increment NumVotes with thread safety and minimal locking.

I've managed to put toegther a stored proc that works but I have 2 questions that are beyond my expertise.

1. Can the stored proc I've put together be improved or is it adequate should 10, 20 or 30 updates occur simultaneously?
2. Is the string index going to be a problem.

SiteCode - varchar(3)

NumVotes - int (more than 1 vote can be added at once)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ComparisonStats_Update

    @SiteCode varchar(3),
    @IncNumVotes int

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    MERGE ComparisonStats  WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS t
    USING (SELECT @SiteCode AS SiteCode, @IncNumVotes AS IncNumVotes) as s
    ON t.SiteCode = s.SiteCode
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
         NumNumVotes += IncNumVotes
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT (SiteCode, NumNumVotes)
        VALUES (s.SiteCode, s.IncNumVotes);
END
```

Comment: Though you'll likely get an answer here, this is a good question for codereview.stackexchange.com since your question could draw "opinions" for question #1